# Fixed элемент за пределами родителя fixed элемента со скролом

Tags: html, css

Можно ли в элементе где есть скролл (overflow auto), и который имеет position fixed.
Сделать внутри элемент тоже fixed, но видимый вне этого элемента?

Если так делаю, то элемент становится невидимым, как только выходит за пределы видимости элемента.

Comment: но видимый вне этого элемента <-- можете объяснить подробнее эту часть?

Comment: так? https://jsfiddle.net/soledar10/g2wstbek/